# Trying to figure out why my quiz isn't registering my answer when submitted

Tags: javascript, html

So at the moment, the quiz keeps looping through the quiz until it switches to the endQuiz Function. What I am trying to do is determine if the answer is equal to the ID in the array when it has been checked, so I callback to the function called selectedAnswer. So when I can call back to it later in the displayNextQuestion so it can show that it is equal to the filteredQuestion[randomQuestion].answer resulting in the score being increase. This is what I have been working on

```js
let easyDifficulty = document.getElementById("easy-diff");
let mediumDifficulty = document.getElementById("medium-diff");
let hardDifficulty = document.getElementById("hard-diff");
let difficulty = document.getElementById("difficulty");
let difficultyLevel = "";
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
let questionCounter = 1;
let maxQuestion = 10;

let questions = [{
  question: `Al Pacino starred in the 1975 film Dog Day Afternoon that is the true story of a 
bank robbery gone bad. Where did the attempted robbery take place?`,
  a: `Chicago`,
  b: `Los Angeles`,
  c: `Boston`,
  d: `New York`,
  answer: `d`,
  difficulty: `hard`,
},
{
question: `Al Pacino and Robert De Niro have starred in a total of four movies together, can you name the film that they first shared screen time in?`,
a: `Righteous Kill`,
b: `Heat`,
c: `The Godfather Part II`,
d: `The Irishman`,
answer: `b`,
difficulty: `hard`,
  },
  {
question: `Al Pacino has starred in the The Godfather Trilogy, can you name the charter he portrays?`,
a: `Fredo Corleone`,
b: `Michael Corleone`,
c: `Tom Hagen`,
d: `Sonny Corleone`,
answer: `b`,
difficulty: `medium`,
  },
  {
question: `Al Pacino starred in the 1973 film Serpico that was director by which director?`,
a: `Sidney Lumet`,
b: `David Lean`,
c: `Mel Brooks`,
d: `Alfred Hitchcock`,
answer: `a`,
difficulty: `medium`,
  },
  {
question: `Al Pacino starred in 2019 film The Irishman, can you pick the actor who doesn't co-star in the film`,
a: `Robert De Niro`,
b: `Christopher Walken`,
c: `Joe Pesci`,
d: `Harvey Keitel`,
answer: `b`,
difficulty: `easy`,
  },
  {
question: `Al Pacino portrays Michael Corleone in the Godfather Trilogy that was directed by which director?`,
a: `George Lucas`,
b: `Stanley Kubrick`,
c: `Francis Ford Coppola`,
d: `Roman Polanski`,
answer: `c`,
difficulty: `easy`,
  }
 ]

let pickDifficulty = () => {
if (easyDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "easy";
} else if (mediumDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "medium";
} else if (hardDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "hard";
}
};

function displayQuestion(quizQuestion, quiz) {
  quizQuestion.querySelector("#question").innerText = quiz.question;
  quizQuestion.querySelector("#a-answer").innerText = quiz.a;
  quizQuestion.querySelector("#b-answer").innerText = quiz.b;
  quizQuestion.querySelector("#c-answer").innerText = quiz.c;
  quizQuestion.querySelector("#d-answer").innerText = quiz.d;
}

difficulty.addEventListener("change",() => {
pickDifficulty();
const filteredQuestions = questions.filter((question) => 
question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
const randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() 
*filteredQuestions.length);
const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz");
const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode;
quiztemplate.forEach((qq) => quizparent.removeChild(qq));
let quizQuestion = 
quizparent.appendChild(quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));
displayQuestion(quizQuestion, filteredQuestions[randomQuestion]);
//filteredQuestions.splice(randomQuestion, 1);
},true);

let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

function selectedAnswer() {
  let answer = undefined;

  answers.forEach((answers) => {
    if (answers.checked) {
      answer = answers.id;
    }
  });
  return answer;
}

let score = 0;

function nextQuestion() {

  if (questionCounter >= maxQuestion) {
    endQuiz();
  } else {
    const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz");
    const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode;
    quiztemplate.forEach((qq) => quizparent.removeChild(qq));
    const quizquestion = quizparent.appendChild(quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));

    const filteredQuestions = questions.filter((question) =>
      question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
    const randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuestions.length);
    //filteredQuestions.splice(randomQuestion, 1);

    displayQuestion(quizquestion, filteredQuestions[randomQuestion]);
  }

  let answer = selectedAnswer();
  const filteredQuestions = questions.filter((question) => question.difficulty ===
    difficultyLevel);
  const randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuestions.length);

  if (answer) {
    if (answer === filteredQuestions[randomQuestion].answer) {
      score++;
      document.getElementById(
        "score-counter"
      ).innerHTML = `<h3>Score:${score} / ${maxQuestion}</h3>`;
    }
  }
  }
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
```

```html
   <div id="difficulty" class="center">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" 
    value="easy">
        <label for="easy-diff">Easy</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" 
    value="medium">
        <label for="medium-diff">Medium</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" 
    value="hard">
        <label for="hard-diff">Hard</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="question-holder" class="hide">
  <div id="question-counter"></div>
  <div id="score-counter"></div>
  <p id="post"></p>
  <div class="quiz">
    <h4 id="question">Question placement</h4>
    <ul id="answer-holder">
      <li>
        <label for="a" id="a-answer">possible answer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="b" id="b-answer">possible answer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c" id="c-answer">possible answer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="d" id="d-answer">possible answer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check the console in the snippet I created from your code. There some fundamental logic and syntax issues.

Comment: Is there a way to point to where in the code snippet the problem is occurring? I have more code, just taught I added what was neccarily

Comment: the code snippet is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a rewrite to a large extent. I tried to set up the whole thing without relying too much on (calculated) `id` attributes. Instead I used CSS selectors based on class and parent-child relationships.

I also changed your answers into `choices`, a property containing an array with the options "a" to "d".

The random  sequence of questions was achieved by shuffling the selcted questions using a Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm.

```js
const questions=[{question: "Al Pacino starred in the 1975 film Dog Day Afternoon that is the true story of a bank robbery gone bad. Where did the attempted robbery take place?",choices:["Chicago","Los Angeles","Boston","New York"],answer: "d", difficulty: "hard"},{question: "Al Pacino and Robert De Niro have starred in a total of four movies together, can you name the film that they first shared screen time in?",choices:["Righteous Kill","Heat","The Godfather Part II","The Irishman"],answer:"b",difficulty: "hard"},{question: "Al Pacino has starred in the The Godfather Trilogy, can you name the character he portrays?",choices:["Fredo Corleone","Michael Corleone","Tom Hagen","Sonny Corleone"],answer: "b",difficulty: "medium" },{question: "Al Pacino starred in the 1973 film Serpico that was director by which director?",choices:["Sidney Lumet","David Lean","Mel Brooks","Alfred Hitchcock"],answer: "a",difficulty: "medium"},{question: "Al Pacino starred in 2019 film The Irishman, can you pick the actor who doesn't co-star in the film",choices:["Robert De Niro","Christopher Walken","Joe Pesci","Harvey Keitel"],answer:"b",difficulty: "easy"},{question: "Al Pacino portrays Michael Corleone in the Godfather Trilogy that was directed by which director?",choices:["George Lucas","Stanley Kubrick","Francis Ford Coppola","Roman Polanski"],answer: "c",difficulty: "easy"},{question: "Where did the Boston Tea party take place?",choices: ["Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "New York"],answer: "c",difficulty: "easy"},{question: "When did the United States declare their independence?",choices: [1492, 1776, 1812, 1918],answer: "b",difficulty: "easy"}, {question: "Where is Venice Beach?",choices: ["Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "New York"],answer: "b",difficulty: "easy"}],
    question = document.querySelector("#question"),
    answers = document.querySelectorAll("#answer-holder label span"),
    qcount = document.querySelector("#question-counter"),
    qtotal = document.querySelector("#questions-total"),
    acount = document.querySelector("#score-counter");

  function shfl(a){ // Durstenfeld shuffle
   for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
    j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
    if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
   }
   return a
  }
  function nextQ() { // get next question of filtered and shuffled selection
    if (questions.Q=questions.sel.shift()){
      question.textContent = questions.Q.question; 
      answers.forEach((a, i) =>{
        a.textContent = questions.Q.choices[i];
        a.previousElementSibling.checked=false;
      })
    } else console.log("Game over.")
  }
  document.querySelectorAll("input[name=level]").forEach(
   lvl=>lvl.onclick=_=>{ // filter questions according to level and shuffle them into questions.sel
     questions.sel=shfl(questions.filter(q=>q.difficulty==lvl.value));
     qcount.textContent=acount.textContent="0";
     qtotal.textContent=questions.sel.length;
     nextQ();
   }
  )
  document.querySelector("button").onclick=_=>{ // submit button ==> submit answer
   if (questions.Q){ // only after game is initialised ...
     const ans=document.querySelector("#answer-holder input:checked")
     ++qcount.textContent;
     if (ans?.value == questions.Q.answer) ++acount.textContent;
     nextQ();
   }
  }
```

```html
<div id="question-holder" class="hide">
<label><input type="radio" name="level" value="easy">easy</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="level" value="medium">medium</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="level" value="hard">hard</label><br><br>
<div>Questions: <span id="question-counter"></span> / <span id="questions-total"></span></div>
<div>Correct answers: <span id="score-counter"></span></div>
<p id="post"></p>
<div class="quiz">
  <h4 id="question">Question placement</h4>
  <ul id="answer-holder">
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="a"><span>possible answer</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="b"><span>possible answer</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="c"><span>possible answer</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="d"><span>possible answer</span></label></li>        </ul>
</div>
<button id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I finally got it to work after a couple of adjustments but was wondering how would I add to it to stop it from going to the next question if one of the answers isn't checked at the moment it can loop through the question without checking a box. If you can't answer no problem, but thank anyway really appreciate the help.